# WordPress | Text email issue

Tags: wordpress, email

I am trying to modify the reset-password notification e-mail, but the issue is that the e-mail body is auto-wrapped every ~26 characters.

Is there a way to overcome that issue ?

My message variable is this :

```
$message    =   sprintf(__('Το Όνομα χρήστη (User Name) του λογαριασμού σας MySiteTitle είναι : %s', 'z'), $user_login)  . "\r\n\r\n";
$message    .=  __("Σε περίπτωση που θέλετε να δημιουργήσετε νέο κωδικό πρόσβασης πατήστε τον ακόλουθο σύνδεσμο.", 'z') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message    .=  $link . "\r\n\r\n";
$message    .=  __('Εάν δεν αιτηθήκατε της συγκεκριμένης υπενθύμισης αγνοείστε το παρόν μήνυμα.', 'z');
```

and the send message I get both in my regular e-mail and the Gmail email account is the following:

```
Το Όνομα χρήστη (User Name) του
λογαριασμού σας MySiteTitle είναι
: admin

Σε περίπτωση που θέλετε να
δημιουργήσετε νέο κωδικό
πρόσβασης πατήστε τον
ακόλουθο σύνδεσμο.

http://www.mysite.dch/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=dWBF1extfudBP6Yrrq1P&login=admin

Εάν δεν αιτηθήκατε της
συγκεκριμένης υπενθύμισης
αγνοείστε το παρόν μήνυμα.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a div to solve this issue :
`<div style="width:600px;"></div>`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the HTML is not seem to work fine. I have try to wrap the url "http://www.mysite....." into an anchor tag but I am getting back the html entities for the < > characters and the anchor tag as a text

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after a lot of hours of research.

Following the solution I have applied for other users may have the same issue in the future:

The `wp_mail` function, initiating a new PHPMAiler object. This object among the other properties has own called WordWrap. This property controlling the length of the text lines.

In order to change this property, or any of the properties of the WPMailer object execute the following code in your funcions.php.

```
function mailWordWrap($ar)
{
    $ar->WordWrap = 150;
    return $ar;
}

add_action('phpmailer_init',    'mailWordWrap', 10, 1);
```